# Галерея javascript/mootools

Tags: javascript

Всем привет. 
Передо мной стоит такая задача. Есть галерея написанная на mootools. Нужно её доработать так, чтобы при наведении на изображение: 1) изображение затемнялось 2) и на фоне изображения выводился текст.
Как это реализовать? Может можете посоветовать какие нибудь плагины mootools? 
Практические примеры приветствуются. Заранее спасибо.
Jet.

Да. Галерея YooGallery.

Comment: Хоть покажите галерею, народу легче будет понять о чем речь )

Answer (score 2):

Нужно на изображение наложить блок с display:none, черным фоном и прозрачностью. В момент hover, мы плавно показывем этот див, который будет затемнять картинку за ним. Текст с описанием можно хранить в каком нибудь атрибуте картинки и потом его доставать и записывать его в тот див на нужное место (можно этот див с текстом сгенерировать скриптом либо все сразу на сервере)